# Perl print loop and replace print result before

Tags: perl

Its posible to replace print result in perl output

Contents of Simple.csv:

```
string1
string2
string3
```

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = 'simple.csv';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
while( my $line = <$info>)  {
    sleep(2);
    print $line ;
}

close $info;
```

output its like:

```
string1
string2
string3
```

How to change the output in single line replace each other like  string1 ..then replace string2... then replace string 3

Comment: Sorry I think you need to clarify this question a bit. What exactly are you trying to do and what have you already tried?

Comment: thanks for response, so iwant the output like replace each other

Comment: input please...?

Comment: You're declaring a variable $file and never using it. Then you're attempting to use a variable $info that you never declared. This shouldn't work at all while using strict;

Comment: simple.csv is containt about string1 string2 strin3 string4 etc

Comment: Exactly what output are you expecting? Don't try to describe it - just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44261703/edit) to show us.

Comment: "i want output insingle line replace each other like string1 ..then replace string2... then replace string 3". And that is exactly why I asked you **not** to describe the output that want, but to **show us**. Look, if you can't be bothered to produce an understandable specification of your problem, then why would you expect us to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` to control the imposition of newline characters.  Use a backspace (`\b`) to move backwards over the last output line, or simply issue a carriage-return (`\r`) to move to the beginning of the line.  Line buffering is also disabled.  Something like this meets your requirement (as I understand it):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = 'simple.csv';
open my $info, '<', $file or die "Can't open '$file': $!\n";
$|++;    #...don't buffer output...
while ( my $line = <$info> ) {
    chomp $line;    #...remove ending newline...
  # printf "%s%s", $line, "\b" x length($line);  # alternative-1
    printf "%s\r", $line;                        # alternative-2
    sleep 2;
}
close $info;
print "\n";         #...leave a clean output...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, print statement itself can do that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = 'simple.csv';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
while( my $line = <$info>)  {
        chomp($line);
        print "$line\r";
        sleep(2);
}

close $info;
```

This Carriage return moves to the beginning of the line for each print.